# spring data, hibernate, can not save related entity in requared new transaction

Tags: hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have `Entity` with relationship to this entity.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHARGES")
public class Charge {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GUID", nullable = false)
    private String guid;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORIGIN_CHARGE_GUID")
    private Charge chargeOrigin;

    @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE")
    private Boolean isActive;
```

Column `IS_ACTIVE` has constraint(only one `Charge` can be `true`)

Each Charge I save in methos with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

It is look like this:

```
@Transactional
public void mainMethod { // Root transaction
      for (Charge charge: charges) {
        //try
        saveOneCharge(charges);
        //catch
    }
 }

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)//internal transaction
public Charge saveOneCharge(Charge charge) {
    return chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(charge);
}
```

But now I need change `isActive`  in both charges:

```
charge.seActive(True);
charge.getChargeOrigin().setActive(false);
chargeService.saveOneCharge(charge)
```

and I get exception(constraint exception)

I need change this code to:

```
charge.setIsActive(false);
charge.getChargeOrigin().setActive(false);
Charge deactivatedCharge = chargeService.saveAndFlush(charge.getChargeOrigin());
charge.setChargeOrigin(deactivatedCharge);
chargeService.saveOneCharge(charge)
```

But in this case my server not throw exceptions, and hangs.

**EDIT**

I rewrote the code a little while looking for the answer and here is a part of the real project:

```
@Transactional
private void methodWithMainTransaction() {

        for (Charge charge: charges) {
            chargeService.changeChargeActivation(charges);
        }
```

service method:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Charge changeChargeActivation(Charge charge) {
    Charge chargeOrigin = charge.getChargeOrigin();
    if (chargeOrigin != null) {
        chargeOrigin.setIsActive(!chargeOrigin.getIsActive());
        chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(chargeOrigin);
    }
    charge.setIsActive(!charge.getIsActive());
    return chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(one);
}
```

On line `chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(chargeOrigin);` the server just hangs without errors

Comment: Your `@Transaction(REQUIRES_NEW)` is useless. You are doing an internal method call, that doesn't pass through the proxy and hence doesn't get interpreted. You get the exception due the the flush, but everything is still in a single tx. This code does actually break your tx, due to the try/catch.

Comment: @M. Deinum in real project method with `@Transaction(REQUIRES_NEW)` contains in another class(service)

Comment: Please let your question reflect that, to prevent wrong assumptions.

Comment: @M. Deinum I eddited my question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)` in your entity?

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORIGIN_CHARGE_GUID")
private Charge chargeOrigin;
```

This should update the `chargeOrigin`, when you update your `charge`. Also, you could always merge the old charge and the update the new one.

```
charge.setIsActive(true);
Charge oldCharge = chargeService.findById(charge.getChargeOrigin().getGuid());
oldCharge.setActive(false);
chargeService.saveOneCharge(oldCharge);
chargeService.saveOneCharge(charge);
```

In this last case, you shouldn't have the `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)` annotation in your entity.